# Magento 1.9.1 security patch failed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, magento, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

I know it might be a duplicate question but I tried all answers of SO but nothing is working.

I am applying security patches on my `magento 1.9.1` but all patches are failed. 
I am using `AWS EC-2` with `php7` and `ubuntu 16.04`.
[image]

I have tried almot every [answers](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ubuntu%20all%20security%20patchs%20failed%20magento&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=CDQ6WYPqL4jy8AfB4ZD4Bg#q=PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh:%2014:%20PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh:%20127:%20not%20found&filter=0)

I have spent approx 2 hours and try with changing permission, running with bash, sh, ./path_path, chmod -x patch and others but same result every time.
.

Answer (score 0):

The hunk error normally came because it will not match the file lines. In this case you can do 2 things.

1. Replace mention files with new same version Magento setup and then try to install the patch using SSH.
2. Install the patch manually and then do your modifications on it.

Thanks.